# How do I design a Animoji 3D model used by ARKit?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, scenekit, arkit

I want to create an Animoji in my APP. But when I contact with some designers they didn't know how to design an Animoji 3D model. Where can I find a solution for reference?

Solution I can thought is create many bones on face of 3D model, And when I get `blendShapes` of `ARFaceAnchor`, which contain the detail information of face expression, then I use it to update bone animations of partial face.

Thank you for reading. Any advises is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, to clear the air a bit: Animoji is a product built on top of ARKit, not in any way a feature of ARKit itself. There's no simple path to "build a model in *this format* and it 'just works' in (or like) Animoji".

That said, there are multiple ways to use the face expression data vended by ARKit to perform 3D animation, so how you do it depends more on what you and your artist are comfortable with. And remember, for any of these you can use as many or as few of the blend shapes as you like, depending on how realistic you want the animation to be.

#### Skeletal animation

As you suggested, create bones corresponding to each of the blend shapes you're interested in, along with a mapping of blend shape values to bone positions. For example, you'll want to define two positions for the bone for the `browOuterUpLeft` parameter such that one of them corresponds to a value of 0.0 and another to a value of 1.0 and you can modulate its transform anywhere between those states. (And set up the bone influences in the mesh such that moving it between those two positions creates an effect similar to the [reference design](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor.blendshapelocation/2928274-browouterupleft) when applied to your model.)

#### Morph target animation

Define multiple, topologically equivalent meshes, one for each blend shape parameter you're interested in. Each one should represent the target state of your character for when that blend shape's weight is 1.0 and all other blend shapes are at 0.0.

Then, at render time, set each vertex position to the weighted average of the same vertex's position in all blend shape targets. Pseudocode:

```
for vertex in i..<vertexCount {
    outPosition = float4(0)
    for shape in 0..<blendShapeCount {
        outPosition += targetMeshes[shape][vertex] * blendShapeWeights[shape]
    }
}
```

An actual implementation of the above algorithm is more likely to be done in a vertex shader on the GPU, so the `for vertex` part would be implicit there — you'd just need to feed all your blend shape targets in as vertex attributes. (Or use a compute shader?)

If you're using SceneKit, you can let Apple implement the algorithm for you by feeding your blend shape target meshes to [`SCNMorpher`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmorpher).

[This is where the name "blend shape" comes from, by the way.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morph_target_animation) And rumor has it the built-in `ARFaceGeometry` is built this way, too.

#### Simpler and Hybrid approaches

As you can see in [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences), you can go even simpler — breaking a face into separate pieces (nodes in SceneKit) and setting their positions or transforms based on the blend shape parameters.

You can also combine some of these approaches. For example, a cartoon character could use morph targets for skin deformation around the mouth, but have floating 2D eyebrows that animate simply through setting node positions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This  is very illuminating to me!

Comment: Illuminating? No, lighting and shading is a whole other question. 

Answer (score 0):

Check-out the ['weboji' javascript library on gitHub](https://github.com/jeeliz/jeelizWeboji). The CG artists we hired to create the 3D models get used with the workflow in minutes. Also, it could be an interesting approach to avoid proprietary formats and closed ecosystem issues.

[Screenshots of a 3D Fox (THREE.JS based demo) and a 2D Cartman (SVG based demo).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLWP9.jpg)

[Demo on youtube featuring a 2D 'Cartman'.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WxaL_kXwtRE)